# C++ template return parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I want a function that just return template type, but not accept any as parameters.
But my

```
template <typename T>
T getSomeT() {
  T some;
  return some;
}
```

did not work, it says "`error: no matching function for call to 'getSomeT'`" and "`note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'`"

But it work just fine if I add some fake template parameter in it:

```
template <typename T>
T getSomeT(T fake) {
  T some;
  return some;
}
```

Comment: Use imallett's answer, but also note that this will only work for objects with a default constructor and a copy constructor.

Comment: If you need the type of an expression, you can use `decltype(expr)` since C++11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error tells you, "`couldn't infer template argument 'T'`".

So tell it:

```
int result = getSomeT<int>();
```

Comment: Thanx, get it. Thought it can infer type from leftside int

Comment: @user3537411 N.B. it can't infer from the left side because of implicit casting/construction. It's the same reason functions cannot be overloaded by return type alone. E.g. changing `<int>` to `<short>` would also work in the above. See also [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fn-templates-explicit-calls.html).